# How do I delete/unset a buffer local option (such as autoread)?

Tags: buffers, options

In a new buffer, the expression `&l:autoread` evaluates to the value `-1`, indicating that the *local* option `autoread` has not yet been set with `:setl autoread` or `:setl noautoread`.

When I set the local option with `:setl autoread`, the expression evaluates to `1`, when I unset it with `:setl noautoread`, it evaluates to `0`. In either case, I won't be able to automatically have the global value for the option set with `:set autoread`.

So, is there a possibility to completely unset/delete the local option so that the expression `&l:autoread` will evaluate to `-1` again?

Comment: What you describe seems odd. The normal value for the option is 0 or 1. Which version of vim are you using?

Comment: @Luc, I double checked the behaviour, `echo &l:autoread` print `-1` after starting up gvim. `echo v:version` prints `704`.

Comment: My mistake, I was testing `&l:autochdir` which is a global option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could directly set the local option to -1:

```
setl autoread
let &l:autoread=-1
```

At this point `echo &l:autoread` returns -1, and `setl autoread?` outputs `--autoread`, which is the exact same output of a new buffer, meaning that the global value is being used for that option:

```
                                                        *:setl* *:setlocal*
:setl[ocal] ...         Like ":set" but set only the value local to the
                        (...)
                        Without argument: Display local values for all local
                        options which are different from the default.
                        When displaying a specific local option, show the
                        local value.  For a global/local boolean option, when
                        the global value is being used, "--" is displayed
                        before the option name.
```

Comment: This doesn't delete or unset a local option, it set's the local option to be `-1`

Answer (score 0):

To remove a `setlocal` override option such that the global `set` is used instead, you can

```
:setlocal autoread<
```

Comment: `:setlocal autoread&` or some variant?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble
Or simply `:set autoread<`. `:h :set` says: _`:se[t] {option}<` For |global-local| options: Remove the local value of {option}, so that the global value will be used._ To not mistake with `:setlocal autoread<` that'll also copy the global value (as with this answer)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble that actually changes it to the default vim option and not the global option. For example, if `makeprg` is set globally to `make -k -j 4` and I use a compiler that does `setlocal makeprg ...`, then `setlocal makeprg&` will change to `make` and not `make -k -j 4`

Comment: @LucHermitte thank you! That's what I was looking for!